How to uninstall brew-installed Little Snitch with brew?
I recently installed Little Snitch with homebrew to try it out. I'm annoyed now by it bugging me about Demo mode all the time and not making it easy to quit (it auto restarts if killed via htop).
So I've tried to uninstall it with brew uninstall little-snitch. But that failed with some permission errors:
$ brew uninstall little-snitch
==> Uninstalling Cask little-snitch
==> Backing App 'Little Snitch.app' up to '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/little-snitch/
==> Removing App '/Applications/Little Snitch.app'
==> Using sudo to gain ownership of path '/Applications/Little Snitch.app'
Password:
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/CodeResources: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/_CodeSignature: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/MacOS/Little Snitch: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/MacOS: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/MainMenu.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/LSDiagnosticsReport_Alert.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/RuleHelp.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/Rule.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/InspectorView.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/RestoreFactoryDefaultsSheetAccessoryView.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/DisplayStrings.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/BlocklistURLPicker.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/SettingsTerminology.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/DemoAlert.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/LocalRuleGroupInspector.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/RulesCategory_TopBar.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/Installation.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/RemainingTimeFormatter.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/RuleEqualityPopover.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/RulesCategory.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/LicenseAgreement.strings: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/RulesTable.strings: Operation not permitted
...SNIP...
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Info.plist: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/PkgInfo: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents: Operation not permitted
chown: /Applications/Little Snitch.app: Operation not permitted
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/CodeResources

Now if I rerun the uninstall I get the following:
$ brew uninstall little-snitch
==> Uninstalling Cask little-snitch
Error: It seems there is already an App at '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/little-snitch/6.1.1/Little Snitch.app'.

Also the daemon is still running, so the uninstall seems to have completely failed:

What shall I do now? I couldn't find an "Uninstall" button in the Little Snitch UI so I'm stuck.
This question is related but doesn't involve brew: Little Snitch uninstalled properly but Little Snitch Helper still here

See also https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/1801

I created a new issue, as the one @nohillside links was closed and locked despite not being fixed: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/187348

The instructions for uninstalling Little Snitch are here:
https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch6/intro-uninstall
Don't use Homebrew for uninstalling.

Thanks for the link to the uninstall docs. I proposed an edit to point it at the latest version 6 instead of 5 docs: https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch6/intro-uninstall I suppose I should tell Homebrew maintainers to point at those docs rather than trying and failing an uninstall through brew tooling.

IMO, Cask in general is just bad.
